# CE Tweet Plugin set up issue

Tags: templates, plugin, tags

Unfortunately the documentation for [CE Tweet](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet) is unclear so I would like to query the set up and to be guided in the right direction. How do I configure my twitter account details into the plugin?

As mentioned in the CE Tweet documentation I have a created a channel named `twitter` and a channel field group titled `{tweet_feed}`. I am trying to setup a single tweet feed on my site. First I have added `<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>`
 into my template, then I have embedded the following code into my template:

```
{exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline field="tweet_feed" screen_name="CharlesCompany" lang:en' count="1"}
  <div class="ce_tweet">
    <div class="ce_tweet_left">
      <a class="ce_tweet_username" href="http://twitter.com/{user_screen_name}" target="_blank"><img src="{user_profile_image_url}" alt="{alt}" /></a>
    </div><!--CE TWEET LEFT ENDS HERE-->
    <div class="ce_tweet_right">
        <div class="ce_tweet_row">
            <a class="ce_tweet_username" href="http://twitter.com     user_screen_name}" target="_blank">{user_name}</a>
            <a class="ce_tweet_name" href="http://twitter.com/{user_screen_name}" target="_blank">{user_screen_name}</a>
        </div><!-- .ce_tweet_row -->
        <div class="ce_tweet_row ce_tweet_text">{text}</div>
        <div class="ce_tweet_row ce_tweet_actions">
            <a class="ce_tweet_time" href="https://twitter.com/{user_screen_name}/statuses/{id_str}" title="{created_at format="%g:%i %A, %M %j%S (%T)"}" target="_blank"><span class="icon-twitter"></span> {created_at_relative}</a>
            <a class="ce_tweet_reply" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to={id_str}" target="_blank"><span>Reply</span></a>
            <a class="ce_tweet_retweet{if retweeted} ce_tweet_retweeted{/if}" href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id={id_str}" target="_blank"><span>Retweet</span></a>
            <a class="ce_tweet_favorite{if favorited} ce_tweet_favorited{/if}" href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id={id_str}" target="_blank"><span>Favorite</span></a>
        </div><!-- .ce_tweet_row -->
    </div><!-- .ce_tweet_right -->
  </div><!--CE TWEET ENDS HERE --> 
{/exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline}
```

My confusion is what else I need to add in order for my tweets to be visible on my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Have you read the plugin's [user timeline](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet/tags/user_timeline) documentation? It makes no reference to a `field` parameter nor is there any indication that the plugin integrates with the channel module. I'm not sure why you've created a `twitter` channel but it sounds as though you're trying to do something that the plugin doesn't support.
- If ever you're debugging something the first step is usually to remove all extraneous code. The same applies when posting questions to StackExchange. I'd suggest removing everything within the `{exp:ce_tweet:user_timeline}` tags and replacing it with a simple `{text}` var (since that should output the text of individual tweets).
- Recent versions of the Twitter API require OAuth credentials for all requests. I'm not sure which API endpoint this add-on uses but the [installation instructions](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet/installation) make it clear that you need to setup OAuth tokens. Have you done that?

Comment: Cheers, i was wasn't aware of the configuration side of things

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure your API access via ExpressionEngine's config.php file, where you'll need to add this:

```
//CE Tweet
$config['ce_tweet_consumer_key'] = 'consumer_key_here';
$config['ce_tweet_consumer_secret'] = 'consumer_secret_here';
$config['ce_tweet_oauth_token'] = 'access_token_here';
$config['ce_tweet_oauth_secret'] = 'access_token_secret_here';
```

http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet/installation

Answer (score 2):

If you want tweets made by user CharlesCompany then you should be using the `user_timeline` tag which can be found here:

http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet/tags/user_timeline

The search tag is for making search queries and is what you seem to be using in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For the search query, you would need to have additional tags withing {results}{/results}.  see: http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet/tags/search

Comment: Thanks. For some reason my tweets are not display...i have edited my quest with new code

Comment: note sure if this is throwing anything off, but what is lang:en' in the first tag?

Comment: i seen it in the example, i'll remove to see what happens. - I did and still no joy